# How to know the section number on button click of Tableview cell in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView for which I have created a custom UITableViewCell. Each row in tableview has a button. I want to know the section number on click of a button, so that I would know that from which section button has been clicked. I have already tried few things found on stack but nothing is working.

```
UIButton *b = sender; 
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:b.tag inSection:0]; 
NSLog(@"Row %d - Section : %d", path.row, path.section);
```

Comment: Show some code you tried which is not working for you.

Comment: UIButton *b = sender;
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:b.tag inSection:0];
    
    NSLog(@"Row %d - Section : %d", path.row, path.section);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a handler for button click and add it in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button{

    UITableViewCell *cell = button.superView.superView;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    //Now you have indexPath of the cell 
    //do your stuff here

}
```

Comment: better way to do this..
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender{
    id cellView = sender;

    while ([cellView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]] == NO) {
        cellView = [cellView superview];
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)cellView; //Get cell
    
    id view = [cell superview];
    while ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]] == NO) {
        view = [view superview];
    }
    UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)view; //Get tableview   
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
}

Comment: @knocker Thanks for your comment. But I believe `indexPathForRowAtPoint:` is a much recommended one.

Comment: yes, you are correct. my point here is getting cell from button button.superview.superView would not work always.
    id cellView = sender; 
    while ([cellView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]] == NO) 
    { 
        cellView = [cellView superview]; 
    } 
    UITableViewCell cell = (UITableViewCell)cellView; //Get cell id
this would be the proper way..

Answer (score 5):

Don't know what you've tried, but i might do something like this. Doing some pseudocode from memory, here.

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    CGPoint buttonOrigin = [sender frame].origin;
    // this converts the coordinate system of the origin from the button's superview to the table view's coordinate system.
    CGPoint originInTableView = [self.tableView convertPoint:buttonOrigin fromView:[sender superview];

    // gets the row corresponding to the converted point
    NSIndexPath rowIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:originInTableView];

    NSInteger section = [rowIndexPath section];

}
```

If I'm thinking clearly, this gives you flexibility in case the button's not directly inside the `UITableView` cell. Say, if you've nested inside some intermediary view.

Sadly, there doesn't seem to be an iOS equivalent of NSTableView's `rowForView:`

Comment: I would suggest this way instead of doing sender.superView.superView because we can have any level of nest os view but this way work for all.

Comment: But I like to suggest to use this one line instead of two line CGPoint originInTableView = [sender convertPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) toView:self.tableView];. we can use either both will work fine.

Comment: Yeah, @CRDave, that works, too. I fell on the side of verbosity for this answer so it'd be clearer what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your custom UITableViewCell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you should pass it its section as a parameter. It could look like:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

  if (!cell)
  { 
  cell = [[[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier" section:indexPath.section] autorelease];
  }

    return cell;
 }
```

Now your cell knows its section and you can use it when performing click method in `MyCustomCell` class

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

First assign section as a tag to button also add target on button in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    [cell.btnSample setTag:indexPath.section];
    [cell.btnSample addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    ...
}
```

Get Section as tag from sender of IBAction you defined (*buttonClicked* here).

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Section: %d",[sender tag]);
}
```